# How to handle job offer when waiting on other offers?

Tags: job-offer

I've been doing a lot of interviews lately and was offered a position that I'm interested in. I haven't given an answer yet because I want to see if other companies I've interviewed with are also interested and determine the best choice. How should I let the company that has extended an offer know that I'm very interested but want to see if the other companies I've interviewed with are also interested so that I can make the best choice?

Comment: @gnat Yeah, I guess I'll go with the idea of telling the company that I'm far along on a couple other interviews and need a couple more days to determine the best choice. I guess the actual wording of the response is something I worry about. I don't want to make it sound like I'm only interested in the position if other positions don't work out.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Thanks Joe. I'll do that.

Comment: If you tell them that, they could simply decide to move to candidate No 2.  Better tactic would be to ask how much time do you have to decide on their offer . They are not stupid, and understand that you have other options, but it is very likely that they too have backup plan.

Comment: Have they given you a deadline? Have they decided the compensation yet? Have they sent you the full contract yet? If they haven't, then you can't accept it yet. You need to see the full contract before you accept anything. And that includes being able to see the employee manual if the contract refers to it.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk they gave me the compensation which was in the range I requested and reviewed the benefits with me. No deadline on deciding was given though. I just asked for a couple days to think it over on Friday. I was thinking of asking if I could give a definite answer on Wednesday.

Comment: So first, you'll need to contact the other companies, and tell them you've received an offer already and would like to see how quickly they could expedite your interviewing process.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I've done that with one company so far. I guess I'm really only interested in the one other company. I have two more interviews setup for tomorrow that I'm still planning on doing but it's probably too late unless they can move very fast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First decide how long you want to delay deciding for. It's unprofessional at best to leave it open ended.

Then just ask for that amount of time to decide due to personal commitments. They will either come back with their own timeframe or more information. Either way you have something to move forwards with.

Comment: They may also come back with "don't worry, we went with someone else". I think it's important to acknowledge that there is a risk involved with this play. Just because you were offered the job, don't assume you were unchallenged by other applicants. It may have comedown to a flip of the coin, and they may approach their second choice while you are busy "thinking about it". I am not suggesting it is common, just that it should be considered.

Comment: @musefan, there's a risk in crossing a road.... but the question isn't about the risk, so the answer isn't either.

Comment: That is why people tend to look before crossing a road, to mitigate the risks. Same with what you say to a potential employee, you consider the risks and act accordingly. Like in your answer, why did you suggest `"due to personal commitments"?` Why not be honest and say, "there is a better job I am waiting to hear back from first"? The answer is of course, because you don't want to take the risk of them changing their mind. Anyway, my comment in just a supporting comment for other readers (who can do whatever they want with it), I am not trying to tell you your answer is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your situation,

I would suggest to go with the flow on the current offer while waiting on others, that may or may not happen

Each company has their own timeline on talent hunting and on-boarding.

If current offer is what you are looking for but you want to wait a bit before committing, check your offer / contract and clarify points that you would usually just dismiss, or leave unattended due to them being a "norm" and "common practice" at your field

It may be a polite clarification question regarding the salary structure, vacation pay, overtime etc  that does not negate the offer, but prolonging the negotiation process

Although in my experience, dragging this too long end up the company going with someone else and the ones you are waiting not sending the offer and checking in you after 3-6 months probing your state in order to scoop you at a cheap depending on the situation