# How to tell recruiter about job offer?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, job-offer

I currently work for A_Company as a contractor, and they've been offering me a job as an employee for a while. Honestly, I've been putting off accepting the offer because I don't particularly want to be an employee there.

On the other hand, I interviewed with Z_Company two weeks ago, and I would prefer working with Z_Company.

Ideally, I would only accept the full-time position at A_Company if I know that Z_Company is not considering me anymore.

How do I tell the Z_Company recruiter this? Is it wise to mention it to her?

Comment: How much is "offering me a job as employee for a while" ... how much is this "for a while"? Is their offer still open?

Comment: Yes, I receive an email weekly requiring me that I apply for the position. I've been putting it off for a month.

Comment: Okey. I would suggest you try to "speed up" this whole process, as I guess you can't keep putting it off for much longer

Comment: Why not just tell Z_Company that you have an offer on your table but would prefer to work for them. And ask if there is a chance to speed up the process. I have been interviewing hundreds of candidates in the last 8 years. And it is not uncommon that We schedule several interviews with one candidate on one day just because the candidate told us that the window is closing in a short time. If they are intertested, then there is always a way to speed update the process.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I tell the Z_Company recruiter this? Is it wise to mention it to her?

I think there is no need to.

If disclosing other offers is wise or not depends on the context and other factors (suggested reading: [How do I coordinate the process of pursuing multiple job opportunities at the same time?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/111/73791). And a more recent post: [How to handle job offer when waiting on other offers?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/174741/73791). Also check the linked posts there), but still, I think doing that in your situation may be unnecessary.

Why? Simply carry on with the process with Z_Company. They give you an offer, go for it. They don't, go for A_Company.

Disclosing you have other offers may be a good bargaining chip, and may "push" the company to make an offer, but I would do as suggested above and carry on with the process and its natural course, and perhaps if Z_Company is lagging, play the other offer card. Timing is also an important factor to consider when taking action.

*Edit:* another suggestion is that given 2 weeks have passed since your interview with Z, it would be a reasonable time to follow-up with them and check what are the next steps, etc..

Comment: I cannot leave A_Company hanging without a response. I don't know how long Z_Company will take to reach a decision.

Comment: @Joe_Hendricks well you've been hanging them without a response for a month... What you are asking (how/if telling Z about A), *could* push Z to make an offer, but that is independent from the recruiting/interviewing process Z has in place (and is no guarantee that Z will give you an offer). As I mentioned and as you can read in linked posts, timing is a critical factor here. I suggest you follow-up with Z asap regarding the process (editing that into the answer)

Answer (score 0):

> How do I tell the Z_Company recruiter this? Is it wise to mention it
> to her?

Why would it not be wise? Your career is in your hands. If you would prefer to work at Z_Company then tell the recruiter for Z_Company that you have another offer but would prefer to work for Z_Company and that you need to know where you stand in the interview/hiring process.